# How to get intellisense for PHP associative array index?

Tags: php, netbeans, phpdoc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHPDoc for variable-length arrays of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009122/phpdoc-for-variable-length-arrays-of-arguments)

Whenever I type `$_SERVER['']` and hit Ctrl + Space it gives me the list of possible indexes. How can I make it possible to array's I've created?

Comment: you can't (but i am not too sure so i am leaving a comment)

Comment: well, all the PHP functions are defined for the purpose of autocomplete in `NetBeans 7.0\php\phpstubs\` but I can't see any reference to `$_SERVER` in there (nor any of the possible values), so I give up. I'll probably be somewhere around there though.

Comment: In the absence of being able to do exactly what you want, I suppose you could define constants for your known set of array keys. If they all start the same, you could get quite good auto-complete from that.

Comment: I do not see how it is a duplicate of "PHPDoc for variable-length arrays of arguments", as PHPDoc and autocompletion are two different things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code completion for `$_SERVER` gives you hints on the typical values people get out of that associative array. It is hard-coded somewhere in the NetBeans source code. For an arbitrary array, NetBeans has no idea of the keys that are used in any array, and thus does not provide hints there. It is even possible to *proof* that it is [impossible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) to reliably implement such a feature, so I think you are out of luck here.

Comment: Its a shame it isn't on the config, as it might be nice to allow users to add their own array that works similarly. Even if it isn't possible to do it reliably, if I have an array in my code which I know will only ever have a known set of keys, it would be nice to be able to add autocompletion for it. Ah well, if it isn't possible it isn't possible, but it would be nice.

Comment: I would still be possible to either implement any kind of hint to the editor what should it suggest OR implement suggestions across array keys let's say in a given file from the keys already used. It would not be able to detect which array it is, but assuming you don't work with many arrays in a single file it might reduce typing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't but the best you can do is to use [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) to document your code.