# Netbeans IDE does not show auto suggestion for php server variables

Tags: php, netbeans

I am looking how to activate auto suggestion in netbeans IDE for server variable.

I want that when I type `$_SERVER[]` then it should show all server variable like it shows in dreamweaver. At present I am using netbeans 7.3.

Anybody know that what may issue due to which I can not see auto suggestion for this server variable?

However it shows functions and other terms in auto suggestion if I use like `$this->` . Problem is with `$_SERVER[]` .

Comment: Follow this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358007/how-to-get-intellisense-for-php-associative-array-index

Answer (score 0):

You can customize auto-completion by going to

```
Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion
```

Choose whatever configuration works best for you.

Hope this will help!

Comment: I did not told that netbeans does not show any autosuggestion. I have mentioned that it shows autosuggestion  for functions and other terms, but does not show autosuggestion for server variable .. $_SERVER.   If you will type $_SERVER in dreamweaver then you can see all server variable like REMOTE_ADDR etc in autosuggestion listbox. This does not happen in netbeans.     Do you know what is problem ? or is this netbeans bugs ?