# PHPStorm + PHPdoc - can I type hint individual array element?

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have:

```
$myarr['DB'] = new DB();
$myarr['config'] = new config();
```

Can I make somehow PHPStorm to know what exactly inside thouse keys? For now I see only hinting fo variables and class properties, but not array keys.

Comment: In general: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata (but it seems a bit broken? right now).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Late answer, but things have changed.

According to [2021.2 changelist](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/2021-2/#array-shapes) it is possible now to define shape of a simple array with one line comment:

```
/**
 * @return array{id: int, name: string, object: \Of\Some\Class}
 */
function getArray(): array {...}
```

> If there are object-like arrays in your code, you can now define their structure with this PHPDoc annotation: array{key: type, key: type, ...}.
>
> PhpStorm provides code completion for such annotated arrays, reducing the time you spend on routine typing and protecting you from mistakes.
>
> The support is limited to one-line array shape definitions. For larger structures, it is often better to use real objects and classes.

Unfortunatelly I have not found a way to define structure of multi dimensional array, and it would be great to annotate a list of such "shaped" arrays...

Answer (score 4):

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9927-deep-assoc-completion

[image: Type hints from associative array like a champ]

Image from the plugin's github repo. I use the plugin and can confirm it performs as described.

Comment: I use this plugin and yes, it works like a charm ***as long as all assets are loaded within the project scope***

Answer (score 3):

You can define the array keys in advance, then PHPStorm will suggest them (CTRL+space)

```
$my = array();
$my['qwe'] = '';
$my['asd'] = '';
$my['zxc'] = '';

$my['']// inside '' will be autosuggest
```

You can also use phpdoc (CTRL+Q):

```
/**
 * keys:
 * <pre>
 * some_array   (array)
 * some_bool    (boolean)
 * some_double  (double)
 * some_nice_integer    (integer)
 * </pre>
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray(){
    // return some array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-59083/recognize-use-of-list-with-array-shapes
it is possible now to describe even item shape in the list:

```php
/**
 * @return array<int, array{id: int, name: string}>
 */
function getShapedArray(): array {...}
```

Works nice with for loops, but no completion when:

```
$array = getShapedArray();
$elementId = 2;
// No completion for name property.
$array[$elementId]['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This functional is not realized yet in PhpStorm. Vote for [support array access](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17116) feature request.

Also you can try [silex idea plugin](https://github.com/Sorien/silex-idea-plugin).

Comment: Think it more about when PHP knows structure at first place. I, for example, returning rows with JSON from DB witch decoded then to 4D array, and it good to have hinting for theme. But only way to do it is PHPdocking, and sadly there is no syntax for that=(

Answer (score 0):

This can be done inline. Array shapes were added in [phpStorm as of 2021](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/whatsnew/2021-2/#array-shapes).

```
/* @var $myarr array{DB: DB, config: config}*/
$myarr['DB'] = new DB();
$myarr['config'] = new config();
```

Answer (score -1):

For an arbitrary array, PHPStorm has no idea of the keys that are used in any array, and thus does not provide hints there. It is even possible to proof that it is [impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) to reliably implement such a feature, so I think you are out of luck here.

Collected From:

[Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358007/how-to-get-intellisense-for-php-associative-array-index)

Comment: Don't think that DHPdocing class properties is somewhat more reliable. Why not to make feture to PHPdoc array keys? Especially useful when working with service containers.

Comment: Not Impossible, just difficult. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9927-deep-assoc-completion works like a champ with no apparent performance reduction (phpStorm is a bit of a beast so another second or so generating an index would go unnoticed). Been using it for a few days in laravel and WP projects - its lovely.

Answer (score -4):

```
$obj = (object)[]; // Cast empty array to object

add properties:
$obj->x = 'some'
$obj->y = 'hints'
```

Now, PHPStorm, when typing `$obj->` ..... hints x and y

Comment: Avoid type casting by using `new stdClass()`.